# Why can't I view this user image?

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I can see [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478455/mohammad-kanan) image from [outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411504/9730434) the profile:

[image]

But I can't see it from the profile. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The URL of the image in the profile seems to be resized to 328x328.
Imgur doesn't seem to be able to resize the image correctly.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/93wkm.jpg?s=328&g=1

This shows as below:

[image]

If I change the size to say <s>400</s> even 329

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/93wkm.jpg?s=329&g=1

it works:

[image]

Comment: It's a bug?     .?\

Comment: More likely the user uploaded an image of odd size... But that is just a guess.

Comment: Or the conversion failed and the result was incorrectly cached

Answer (score -12):

I think you have used this css,
    .classname {overflow : hidden}
     remove this property 
    then you can see images out side div

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @DavidPostill If this was actually true, it would be an answer imo (a weird one, accusing the poster of using custom CSS). The problem is that it's just plain wrong.